# I can not read a csv with different formats in 1 column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a .csv which contains 20+ columns.
The problem is that I have a column which contains 0, 1, "(10,12), "(20,11)", 9
When trying to read it in a dataframe using read_csv the "" values are not parsed.
What can I use to parse that (10,12) value in a cell?

I tried using all the read_csv options like quotechar, quoting and doublequote. Didn't help. I tried replacing " but that splits the value in 2 columns.

Comment: Please provide the exact content of a minimal example of the CSV. You're mentioning a "column", did you mean a *row*? If this is a row, then your CSV is unfortunately invalid.

Comment: Do you mean you want to split `(10,12)` to two columns?

Comment: did you check if you get it as `str` or `tuple`? IF you have string `(10,12)` then maybe use `eval()` to convert it to tuple.

Comment: maybe you should write script which will use standard `open()`, `read()`, `write()` and it will clear data - and later you can read it with `pandas`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your example is that your quotes are unbalanced:

```
0, 1, "(10,12), "(20,11)", 9
```

Should be:

```
0, 1, "(10,12)", "(20,11)", 9
```

You can fix this by checking for `),` and adding the missing quote (example here using a regex). In addition, the space between the command the the quote is not accepted by the parse by default. To avoid this you have to pass `skipinitialspace=True` to [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```py
import io
import re
import pandas as pd

with open('my_csv.csv') as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(re.sub(r'(\))\s*(,)', r'\1"\2', f.read())),
                     skipinitialspace=True,
                     header=None, # optional, only if you have no header
                     )
```

Output:

```
   0  1        2        3  4
0  0  1  (10,12)  (20,11)  9
```

Answer (score 0):

When reading the csv-file, use the dtype-argument and set it to string.
Then you still habe tuples or integer values in your dataframe column, but as string.

After that, write a function, that parses the column in the way you need it.

```
df = pd.read_csv("my_csv.csv", dtype=str)
```

Comment: This is not the issue, the CSV is invalid and cannot be parsed correctly